# What is find() doing in this HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am somewhat unfamiliar with JavaScript and very unfamiliar with Angular, so if you are familiar with these it will be a basic question. I have inherited an HTML form with the following:

```
<form ng-submit="find()">

SOME STUFF

<button id="find-button" ng-click="find()" ng-show="findBox.findType != FIND_ALL">Search</button>

MORE STUFF

</form>
```

My question is...what is the find() function doing when the SEARCH button is clicked? Is this some kind of built in function, and if so, what is it doing? I can't find any documentation on it anywhere. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `find()` would be defined in the javascript file somewhere. It looks like the form relies heavily on angular.

Comment: It could be window.find(), but I highly doubt it is. Probably just some global function. Open up console and type `find`, hit enter. and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The find() function is not predefined. It is user created function in javascript. Go look at your js file and find where it defines the function.

Comment: The find() function is called in choose-chems.html. In choose-chems.js I find something called "$scope.find = function ()". I am assuming this must be the find() that I seek.

Comment: Yes indeed. In angular, controllers pass a $scope object that you can assign properties to... 
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myctrl', function($scope){
...
    $scope.find = function () {
        (this is where your logic should end up)
    }
...
});

Answer (score 0):

`find()` is implemented on the page somewhere as a function in that context.  You'd have to dig around your JS files to determine what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Find the function find in your whole project, try searching for

function find(

or

var find = function(

The one you mentioned above in a comment (in choose-chems.js the $scope.find = function ()) doesn't seem to be the function you are looking for.